# Restrict SFTP folder with PHP permisions

Tags: sftp, chroot

I want an user to have access to /var/www/domain.com/public_html so I followed this tutorials, but with my modifications so I can have my users upload directly to their domains:

https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/limiting-access-with-sftp-jails-on-debian-and-ubuntu

https://bensmann.no/restrict-sftp-users-to-home-folder/

So, I'm on ubuntu 14.04, and this is what I did:

In my /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

#...
UsePAM yes

Match group www-data
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Also created a user called username and run this commands:

```
sudo usermod username -g www-data
sudo usermod username -d /var/www/domain.com
sudo usermod username -s /bin/false
sudo chown root:root /var/www/domain.com
sudo chmod 0755 /var/www/domain.com
sudo chown -hR username:www-data /var/www/domain.com/public_html
sudo service ssh restart
```

When I try to sftp I get this error

> Write failed: Broken pipe Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by
>   peer

What I am missing?

Comment: also I have checked that all the folders in /var/www/domain.com are chowned to root:root and 755 permissions

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've checked again the permissions and I had them wrong
I just chown root:root and chmod 755 all the path to /var/www/domain.com and now it's working great